# React useState hook isn't updating state as desired

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-state

I'm trying to change the background color of a button to black as mouse hover over it and change it back to white when it's not. I used the state on a string which will change to black or white and pass it in style property. Any idea on where I'm going wrong?

Thank you.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [headingText, setHeadingText] = useState("Hello");
  const [buttonColor, setButtonColor] = useState("White");    //setting the state

  function handleClick() {
    setHeadingText("Submitted");
  }

  function mouseOver() {
    setButtonColor("Black");             //changing state
  }
  function mouseOut() {
    setButtonColor("White");             //changing state
  }

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h1>{headingText}</h1>
      <input type="text" placeholder="What's your name?" />
      <button
        style={{ backgroundColor: { buttonColor } }}    //where I want it to apply
        onClick={handleClick}
        onMouseOver={mouseOver}
        onMouseOut={mouseOut}
      >
        Submit
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use instead `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave` events.

Try as the following:

```
<button style={{ backgroundColor: buttonColor }}
        onClick={handleClick}
        onMouseEnter={mouseOver}
        onMouseLeave={mouseOut} >
```

Read further here in React documentation for [Mouse Events](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#mouse-events).

I hope this helps!

Comment: I found where I made the mistake, I put the buttonColor inside a curly bracket unnecessarily. Anyway thanks. :)

Comment: Just a comment - Or maybe an even better way to use `useHover()` hook, check out here: https://usehooks.com/useHover/

Comment: @VineetPillai Oh, I corrected automatically in my answer but forgot to mention, yes. :D

Answer (score -1):

1. You should use "debounce" to delay the process of mouseOver event. You can reference the link: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/debounce-in-javascript-improve-your-applications-performance-5b01855e086
2. Lodash library supports the debounce function. It is easy to use: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#debounce

import React, { useState } from "react";

```
import { debounce } from 'lodash';

function App() {
  const [headingText, setHeadingText] = useState("Hello");
  const [buttonColor, setButtonColor] = useState("White");    //setting the state

  function handleClick() {
    setHeadingText("Submitted");
  }

  function mouseOver() {
    setButtonColor("Black");             //changing state
  }
  function mouseOut() {
    setButtonColor("White");             //changing state
  }

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h1>{headingText}</h1>
      <input type="text" placeholder="What's your name?" />
      <button
        style={{ backgroundColor: { buttonColor } }}    //where I want it to apply
        onClick={handleClick}
        onMouseOver={debounce(mouseOver, 200)}
        onMouseOut={debounce(mouseOut, 200)}
      >
        Submit
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```